# Adding element to List through reflection

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I try to add an element to a List I retrieved through reflection.

The following line

```
property.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(entity, new[] { innerValue });
```

is throwing an error

> Object does not match target type" (Reflection.TargetException)

But the Types *should* match:

```
string listType=property.PropertyType().FullName; // System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[My.Entities.Task, My.Entities, Version=1.4.6429.20475, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
string elementType=innerValue.GetType().FullName; // My.Entities.Task
```

`entity` is an object that contains the property above

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to invoke `Add` on `entitiy`, not on the list contained in `entity`'s property.

Get the *value* of the property (which should be the list) and invoke `Add` on that reference:

```
var list = property.GetValue(entity);
property.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, new[] { innerValue });
```